# Anyone can explain the "same thing" issue of UTF-8?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

Quoted from [here](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.html#sec-10):

> Security may also be impacted by a characteristic of several character
>   encodings, including UTF-8: the "same thing" (as far as a user can
>   tell) can be represented by several distinct character sequences. For
>   instance, an e with acute accent can be represented by the precomposed
>   U+00E9 E ACUTE character or by the canonically equivalent sequence
>   U+0065 U+0301 (E + COMBINING ACUTE). Even though UTF-8 provides a
>   single byte sequence for each character sequence, the existence of
>   multiple character sequences for "the same thing" may have security
>   consequences whenever string matching, indexing,

Is this a hidden feature of UTF-8 that I've never tackled before?

Comment: I don't understand your question... the quote you posted says it all - since Unicode (which is the base of UTF8 which is just an encoding) supports several character sets etc. the rendered characters of two different unicode codepoints might be the same from a user's perspective... this can be abused in a securiry-impacting way...

Comment: @Yahia, That's not an issue as long as only ONE encoding is used,maybe you can elaborate what you mean as an answer?

Comment: I don't think that we are talking about the same thing... encoding and character set are too very different things... what you say might be true for a character set but is definitely wrong regarding an encoding...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is not actually specific to UTF-8 at all. It happens with all encodings that can represent all (or at least most) Unicode codepoints.

The *general* idea of Unicode is to *not* provide so-called [pre-composed characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) (e.g. [U+00E9 E ACUTE](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=00E9)), *instead* they usually like to provide the base character (e.g. [U+0065 LATIN SMALL LETTER E](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0065)) and the combining character (e.g. [U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=0301)). This has the advantage of not having to provide every possible combination as its own character.

Note: [the U+xxxx notation is used to refer to unicode codepoints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Architecture_and_terminology). It's the encoding-independent way to refer to Unicode characters.

*However* when Unicode was first designed an important goal was to have round-trip compatibility for existing, widely-used encodings, so *some* pre-composed characters were included (in fact *most* of the diacritic characters from the latin and related alphabets are included).

So yes (and **tl;dr**): in a correctly working Unicode-capable application U+00E9 should render the same way *and* be treated the same way as U+0065 followed by U+0301.

There's a non-trivial process called [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) that helps work with these differences by reducing a given string to one of four normal forms.

For example passing both strings (`U+00E9` and `U+0065 U+0301`) will result in `U+00E9` when using NFC and will result in `U+0065 U+0301` when using NFD.

Comment: What is `U+00E9 E ACUTE`, `U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT`??How does it look like?I've never used pre-composed characters...

Comment: @new_perl: I've explained the U+xxxx notation in my answer. Also: you probably used pre-composed characters **a lot** because they are used almost everywhere (despite the Unicode consortium *trying* to get rid of them).

Comment: I just took a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character, but the `U+00C5 U+0073 U+0074 U+0072 U+00F6 U+006D` and `U+0041 U+030A U+0073 U+0074 U+0072 U+006F U+0308 U+006D` are NOT the same, just similar, the position of accent is different...

Comment: @new_perl: they are not the same, because the article effectively disables the composition by trying to color the composition characters differently than the base characters. That *might* render correctly on some browsers, but I doubt that it's conforming to the standard. That's an unfortunate mistake in the article and should be fixed. Apart from that you might be using a browser with an in-perfect composition support.

Comment: I just verified it: on the current Firefox it *does* render correctly, even though the characters are in different colors.

Comment: Why it seldom actually causes trouble then if you said it's used **a lot**?

Comment: Firefox 4.0 is not current ;-) Firefox 7 on my Ubuntu computer *does* render it correctly.

Comment: Does this kind of issue exists for other multibyte character encodings such as gbk,euc-jp etc?

Comment: @new_perl: I don't know enough of those encodings to tell. They are *not* general-purpose Unicode encodings, as far as I know, so they don't suffer the *exact same* problem. They *might* have composite and pre-composed characters however, in which case they'd suffer from a *similar* problem.

Answer (score 3):

Very short and visualized example: the character "é" can either be represented using the Unicode code point U+00E9 (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE, `é`), or the sequence U+0065 (LATIN SMALL LETTER E, `e`) followed by U+0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT, `´`), which together look like this: `é`.

In UTF-8, `é` has the byte sequence `xC3 xA9`, while `é` has the byte sequence `x65 xCC x81`.

<sub>Note: Due to technical limitations this post does not contain the actual combination characters.</sub>

Comment: Depends on what you're coding with. Writing `"\xC3\xA9"` and `"\x65\xCC\x81"` may or may not do the trick in your language of choice. Or on Mac OS X there's a character palette you can use to choose these individual characters...

Comment: Does this kind of  issue exists for other multibyte character encodings such as gbk,euc-jp etc?

Comment: I don't know of other encodings that have the notion of *combining* diacritics and such, **but** I haven't studied most other encodings as much as I have Unicode either. So, I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

> Actually I don't understand what it means by :
>
> "Even though UTF-8 provides a single byte sequence for each character
>   sequence[...]"

What the quote wants to say is:

"Any given sequence of Unicode code points is mapped to one (and precisely one) sequence of bytes by the UTF-8 encoding." That is, UTF-8 is a bijection between sequences of (abstract) Unicode code points and bytes.

The problem, which the text wants to illustrate, is that there is *no* bijection between "letters of a text" (as commonly understood) and Unicode code points, because the same text can be represented by different sequences of Unicode code points (as explained in the example).

Actually, this has nothing to do with UTF-8 specifically; it is a fundamental property of Unicode: Many texts have more than one representations as Unicode code points. This is important to keep in mind when comparing texts expressed in Unicode (no matter in what encoding).

One (partial) solution to this is [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization#Normalization). It defines various *Normal forms* for Unicode text, which are unique representations of a text.

Comment: @new_perl: The information about composition is included in the official "Unicode Character Database" ( http://unicode.org/ucd/ ). I don't know if there is an easy way to extract a list of precomposed characters.

Comment: Why I never have this kind of issues so far?Is it already taken care of by the OS?

Comment: @new_perl: Whether you run into the issue depends on what you do. If you never use precomposed characters (or always use them), the comparison is easy.